# System.out character encoding

Tags: java, windows-7, character-encoding

I'm running my Java program from command-line (Windows 7). To simplify matters, I describe only the relevant part.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Árpád");
}
```

My output is garbage. It is obviously a character-encoding problem, the Hungarian characters of Á and á are not showing up correctly. I've tried the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    ps.println("Árpád");
}
```

But my output is still garbage. How can I resolve this character-encoding issue with Windows 7  command-line? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not a compilation problem? How are you compiling, and what encoding is your source code in?

Comment: Does your display actually support displaying such characters to start with? Ie, can you type them at your keyboard on this display and they appear correctly?

Comment: I'm compiling with NetBeans and the character-encoding of the sources is UTF-8

Comment: Yes, my display supports displaying such characters and I can type my characters correctly. If I run my program from NetBeans it shows the output correctly. I only have problem in showing my result in command-line. This project will be used from command-line by clients who might have Hungarian results.

Comment: Could you test if `Cp852` encoding helps you? In my (Polish) version of Win7 console it is working fine.

Comment: After running chcp 852 my output was the same. I guess this encoding is good for Polish characters, but not for Hungarian. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: As shown here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/country.mspx?mfr=true both Hungarian and Polish character sets are encoded in 850 and 852. But I can't see the big Á in the result, there is a random character instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got your code to work by finding the right encoding from the command line, and then *either* using the `PrintStream` version with that encoding, *or* by specifying it on the command line and just using `System.out.println`.

To find the encoding on the commandline, run `chcp`. Here's the output I got:

```
Active code page: 850
```

That corresponds to the Java charset name of "IBM850". So this then creates the right output on the command line:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=IBM850 Test
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, this almost resolved the problem. The small á character was showing up correctly, the big Á was not showing up correctly.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Both work for me - which code page does your console use?

Comment: It's using 437 by default. I've tried by changing it to 850 and 852, but unfortunately the results were incorrect.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 I suspect it just doesn't support all the characters you need :( It's possible that you can set this elsewhere in Windows - it's not something I've ever done...

Comment: @LajosArpad: Actually, `chcp` will let you *set* the code page as well. So try running `chcp 850` and then the command line I showed in my answer...

Comment: I've tried to run chcp and then the command, without success. Anyway, I thank you for this nice answer, I will start researching the issue based on your ideas and will let you know about the results. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution to the problem, your answer was the closest to a solution, as it allowed small Hungarian characters. I accept this answer as the solution until I find a better solution. Thanks again.

Comment: my solution came with chcp 65001 and not using raster fonts in command prompt

Comment: How to do the same thing in UNIX. I did in Command prompt its works fine for me.

Comment: @user1912935: if the encoding is supported, the exact same command line should work fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is the default code page always 850 for windows cmd.exe environments? If not, does a portable approach exist to resolve this issue for every possible code page set?

Comment: @MRalwasser: No, it isn't - it depends on your regional settings, as far as I'm aware. I don't know of an easy way of detecting it, unfortunately. (I'm sure there is a solution, but it may not be easy and I don't know it anyway!)