# Java string output in Eclipse does not set to utf-8 and does not display öüäñ

Tags: java, string, eclipse, utf-8, special-characters

When I am running this program (I got most of it here: [“UTF-8” encoding is not working in java build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361826/utf-8-encoding-is-not-working-in-java-build)):

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = "¿Hola öäüñ how geht's tú?";
        write(s);
    }

    private static void write(String s) throws IOException {
        String encoding = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out).getEncoding();
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console != null) {
            // if there is a console attached to the jvm, use it.
            System.out.println("Using encoding " + encoding + " (Console)");
            try (PrintWriter writer = console.writer()) {
                writer.write(s);
                writer.flush();
            }
        } else {
            // fall back to "normal" system out
            System.out.println("Using encoding " + encoding + " (System out)");
            System.out.print(s);
        }
    }

}
```

It displays:

```
Using encoding Cp1252 (System out)
�Hola ���� how geht's t�?
```

In the terminal, whereas I want it to dispaly:

```
Using encoding UTF-8(or sth. else that works properly...) (System out)
¿Hola öäüñ how geht's tú?
```

But it doesn't.

I have activated utf-8 in the Project settings, the General settings and under Run configurations > common. And it still is not working. Any clue what I could try next?

Other examples with slightly awkward outcomes:

Line 9:

```
String s = "öäüñ";
```

Terminal:

```
Using encoding Cp1252 (System out)
���
```

Their literary the 'ñ' isn't even a �...?
As well here:

Line 9:

```
String s = "ñ";
```

Terminal:

```
Using encoding Cp1252 (System out)
```

But:

Line 9:

```
String s = "how ñ wow";
```

Terminal:

```
Using encoding Cp1252 (System out)
how � wow
```

And if that could give you a better understanding
this part of code:

```
String str = "¿Hola öäüñ how geht's tú?";  
        //invokes the getBytes() method and stores an array of bytes into array[]  
        byte array[] = str.getBytes("UTF8");  
        System.out.println("Encoded String: ");  
        //enhanced for loop that iterates over the array  
        for (byte x: array)   
        {  
        //prints the sequence of bytes      
        System.out.print(x+" "); 
        }
```

Gives that output in the Terminal:

```
Encoded String: 
-62 -65 72 111 108 97 32 -61 -74 -61 -92 -61 -68 -61 -79 32 104 111 119 32 103 101 104 116 39 115 32 116 -61 -70 63
```

Comment: Your native encoding is not a unicode one. Why would you like it to be?

Comment: Is the same font used in both places?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to enhance your [mcve]. Show us **1st** how do you use the `tester` class, and **2nd** output in the terminal using _all_ problematic characters (at least, `String s = "öäüñ";`).

Comment: @g00se I want it to use UFT-8, to get it to display characters like öäüñ.

Comment: @nitind where can I look up the font?

Comment: *@g00se I want it to use UFT-8, to get it to display characters like öäüñ* You already can:  `System.out.println("\xf6\xe4\xfc\xf1");`

Comment: *@g00se I want it to use UFT-8, to get it to display characters like öäüñ* You already can: `System.out.println("\u00f6\u00e4\u00fc\u00f1");` Apologies for the previous comment - it seems hex escape sequences are no longer supported - I don't know when that happened!

Comment: Interestingly, octal escape sequences (impractical) still work: `System.out.println("\366\344\374\361");`

Comment: Interestingly, octal escape sequences (impractical) still work: System.out.println("\366\344\374\361"); Sorry, but not at my PC it displays: ����

Comment: Could you make that the *only* line of main please and precede it with ```System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));```  and tell us what you get?